How to write a Flex code for matches protocol (http, https), domain name and optional port number, and path of the URL
How to write a Flex code for matches protocol (http, https), domain name and optional port number, and path of the URL
sample input:
http://google.com
https://google.com:6060
https://google.com:6060/gemin
google.com:6060/gemin

sample output :
protocol
domain name


protocol
domain name
optional port number


protocol
domain name
optional port number
path

Invalid URL

this is the code that i have written
%%file task1.l

%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%option noyywrap

%%

(http|https)://([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)(:([0-9]+))?(/[^ \t\n\r\f\v]*)? {
    printf("valid URL\n");
    printf("protocol:%s\n", yytext);
    printf("domain name:%s\n", yytext + 7); // Skip "http://" or "https://"
    if (yytext[strlen(yytext) - 1] == '/') {
        printf("path:/\n");
    } else if (yytext[strcspn(yytext, "\n\r\t\f\v:")] == ':') {
        printf("optional port number:%s\n", yytext + strcspn(yytext, ":") + 1);
        printf("path:%s\n", yytext + strcspn(yytext, "/"));
    } else {
        printf("path:%s\n", yytext + strcspn(yytext, "/"));
    }
}

.|\n    { printf("Invalid URL\n"); }

%%
int main() {
    yylex();
    return 0;
}

there is an error while compile the code,
task1.l:9: unrecognized rule
task1.l:9: unrecognized rule


When you compile? Or when you run lex? And which is line 9?

See RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier and Wikipedia on Uniform Resource Identifier for information on the full syntax.  You'll have to decide what subset of that syntax you are interested in parsing.

Do you need to worry about the // in (http|https)://([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)(:([0-9]+))?(/[^ \t\n\r\f\v]*)? {?  Does using \/\/ change anything?

Post your edit your sample output is not a rational expectation of this code. Pre your edit it was.

Btw, you can replace [ \t\n\r\f\v] with [[:space:]]. All or most of the POSIX character classes are supported. https://github.com/micromatch/posix-character-classes?tab=readme-ov-file#posix-character-classes

And replace [^ \t\n\r\f\v] with [^[:space:]].

This is your input data format:

So, use the Regex:
(http(s)?\:\/\/)?\w+(\d+\w+)?(.com)(\:\d{4})?(\/\w+)?(\s+)?

This will work for you..
